# Is there a specific name for a $[1,n]$ interval as compared to $[0,n]$?

Tags: terminology

Interval $[0,n]$ behaves quite differently to $[1,n]$ if values are used in multiplication, e.g. for scaling other values. Is there a formal terminology to distinguish those?

Comment: What do you mean by "quite differently"?

Comment: @Henrik $[1,n]$ is guaranteed to always scale up, while $[0,n]$ can scale up or down (sorry if my terminology is off here).

Comment: That's a very minor difference, and only correct for positive numbers. I've never heard of any term for that, and don't see any use for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(I'm assuming in both cases you are talking about real number intervals.)*

No, there isn't any official term. You could say one is a closed interval containing $0$ and one is a closed interval not containing $0$.

However, I'm not sure exactly what property that differs between those two intervals you are looking for a term for.